# SQL - number of days between dates grouped by id

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have this data, where each row represent a transaction of a client:

```
Date       Client
2022-01-30 A
2022-01-16 A
2022-01-15 A
2022-03-15 B
2022-02-15 B
2022-03-02 C
```

And I'm looking for the `Number of days` where it's the number of days since the last transaction of that client.

```
Date       Client Number of days
2022-01-30 A      14
2022-01-16 A      1
2022-01-15 A      NULL
2022-03-15 B      30
2022-02-15 B      NULL
2022-03-02 C      NULL
```

I have tried something like this:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Client ORDER BY Date DESC) AS Number_of_days
```

But I'm stuck at `ROW_NUMBER()` as I can't select each date and calculate the difference.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use [LEAD](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/navigation_functions#lead) window function

```
SELECT *,
       DATE_DIFF(Date , LEAD(Date) OVER(PARTITION BY Client ORDER BY Date DESC),DAY) 
FROM T
```

Comment: It works, but you forgot the argument: `DATE_DIFF(DATE, LEAD(DATE) OVER(PARTITION BY Client ORDER BY Date DESC), *DAY*) ` Please fix it to put as an answer :)

Comment: Watch out ! `LEAD` will give the time before the *next* transaction, while `LAG` will give the time since the *last* transaction

Comment: @Chris Sorry What parameter did I forget? I had added `DAY` in function on my original answer

Comment: @Cylldby From the OP question, I believe `LEAD` window function that is right, https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=677a782bba54f063400e571bbff1b874

Comment: @D-Shih indeed ! Sorry I was too hasty, my bad

Comment: @Cylldby Never mind, `LEAD` and `LAG` are very similar I will confuse sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

use lag()

```
select Client,d,
DATE_DIFF(d,lag(d)over(partition by Client order by d desc),DAY) as dys from table_name
```